# Scheduler test class fails while packaging

Tags: apex, managed-package, batch, schedulebatch

**Scheduler Class:**

```
global with sharing class Demo_Scheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(
            new Demo_Batch(new List<My_SObject__c>()),
            1
        );
    }

}
```

**Batch Class:**

```
global class Demo_Batch implements Database.Batchable<WrapperClassData> {

    private List<My_Sobject__c> mylist;
    global Demo_Batch(List<My_Sobject__c> mylist) {
        this.mylist = mylist;
    }

    global Iterable<WrapperClassData> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        //Something happens here
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<WrapperClassData> scope) {
        //performs calculation
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        //Updates Two date fields on My_Sobject__c object
    }

}
```

**Test class for Scheduler**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class Demo_Scheduler_Test {

    private static testMethod Void testScheduler() {
        System.runAs(User_TestFactory.createUserWithPermissionSet(Label.PERMISSIONSET)) {

            Test.startTest();
            //This test runs a scheduled job at midnight Sept. 3rd. of next year
            String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? ' + String.valueOf(Date.today().addYears(1).year());
            String jobId = System.schedule(
                'DemoCalc',
                CRON_EXP,
                new Demo_Scheduler()
            );
            // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobId];

            // Verify the expressions are the same
            System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, cronTrigger.CronExpression);

            // Verify the job has not run
            System.assertEquals(0, cronTrigger.TimesTriggered);

            // Verify the next time the job will run
            String nextRunDate = String.valueOf(Date.today().addYears(1).year()) + '-09-03 00:00:00';
            System.assertEquals(nextRunDate, String.valueOf(cronTrigger.NextFireTime));
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a permission set that has read/write access to date fields `Last_Operation__c` and `Last_Cal_Date__c`. I Assign this permission set to a user I create in my test class.

The batch performs bunch of calculation and then finally updates the above two fields on `My_Sobject__c` object in the finish method.

The test class works fine in my developer org but it fails when I run the test classes in my packaging org (I have a managed package and I'm trying to add this scheduler test class to it).

**Error:**

> Field not updateable by the user: Class.NameSpace.Demo_Batch.finish: line 35, column 1

Which doesn't make sense because the user has permission to update those fields.
In fact I have used the same fields in other test classes and they work just fine.

**EDIT:**
*One thing to note here is that I also have test class specifically for the batch which also uses the same permission set but that just works fine.
I think this has something to with the nature of the class (Scheduler) that I'm unit testing.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81437/discussion-on-question-by-d-k-scheduler-test-class-fails-while-packaging).